# I don't know how to shorten this one

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($(window).width() <961){
        $('.item').on('click',function(){
            /*---do something---*/
        })
    }else{
        $('.item').on('click',function(){
            /*---do something else---*/
        })
    }

    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        if('.nothing-important').is(':visible'){
            $('.item').trigger('click');
        }
    }

}
```

Hello. I need an optimal solution for this. 
When i load page at < 961px it "does something"
and then I resize browser to > 960px and it still "does something" instead of doing "something else". And vice versa.
I guess that it will work if I copy the code into "on.resize" block, but I don't like that solution.
Have a nice day :)

Comment: check the width within the click handler, rather than checking it only once on load

Comment: What does "shortening" it have to do with solving your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move that `if-else` block to the handler of `click` event along with this condition:

```
 if ('.nothing-important').is(':visible') {..}
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.item').on('click', function() {
    if ('.nothing-important').is(':visible') {
       if ($(window).width() < 961) {
         /*---do something---*/
       } else {
         /*---do something else---*/
       }
    }
  });

  $(window).on('resize', function() {        
      $('.item').trigger('click');        
  });
});
```